# Save changes in Browser

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I have created a Website that sort of works like a checklist for Games. You can Add games with the `gameContainer()` Function.

```
const gameContainer = (iconPath: string, name: string, version: string) => {
    const img = document.createElement("img")
    const gameName = document.createElement("a")
    const gameVersion = document.createElement("p")
    const root = document.getElementById("root")
    const gameDiv = document.createElement("DIV")

    root.appendChild(gameDiv)

    img.src = iconPath
    img.className = "gameIcon"
    gameName.innerHTML = name
    gameVersion.innerHTML = version
    
    gameDiv.className = "gameDiv"
    gameDiv.appendChild(img)
    gameDiv.appendChild(gameName)
    gameDiv.appendChild(gameVersion)
}
```

Now, the problem is that if I refresh my page, all games I added disappear. How can I save those changes in my Browser?

I uploaded the source code of my website to GitHub, if you need more info about it: https://github.com/Zockedidock/show-games

Comment: Check the [Local Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Answer (score 0):

in your situation, you just modify the html page to display your data

You can have a look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp)

```
localStorage.setItem("myGames", JSON.stringify(yourGameList));
```

will save your list of videogame

```
console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("myGames")));
```

will print the saved list

That mean you will have to store the list of your videogame in a list and make a function to display that list